# Is it possible to search a dbml diagram?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

This is not an issue with a few tables, but when I have a ton of tables on my dbml diagram, I have to pan and zoom to find the table I am looking for.  Is there a way to search the dbml diagram so it automatically goes to the table I searched for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find (search for) table in DBML designer quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920014/find-search-for-table-in-dbml-designer-quickly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the Designer View you can reach your tables through the usual Method name drop down or searching for the partial classes within the designer.cs. But that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought they would have made this better.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the dropdown in the properties pane to list all the objects in the dbml. Selecting one from the list jumps you to that object in the diagram.

Not perfect but at least its in alphabetical order!

Comment: this is totally the answer here.

Comment: Wow. Finally. I've been looking for this answer for so long. My only regret is that I have but one upvote to give.

Answer (score 1):

I created an AddIns to provide a Search in Diagram for L2S and Entity Framework (VS2008/2010).
http://ormaddins.codeplex.com/

Comment: Although Ronald has unregistered from SO, I would like to emphasize that what he has done is truly appreciated by our team. We are still using VS2010 here and Roland's add-in has saved us (and is continuing to save us) huge amount of time and effort. - THANK YOU SO MUCH RONALD!